# Can't access to Raspberry Pi 3 via Putty

Tags: ssh, pi-3, windows, ethernet-port, putty

I just bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B starter kit. I am a Windows 10 user and I don't have a monitor. I wanted to use Putty to access to my Pi and followed [this](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/) tutorial.

In order to find my Raspberry Pi's IP address, I downloaded the *Advanced IP Scanner* and the *Pi Finder*.

Pi Finder cannot find anything.

Advanced IP Scanner shows me this result:
[image]

Since the status indicator is gray, I believe there is no traffic between my laptop and my Pi. The LEDs on the board are green(right) and orange(left).

If I try to SSH into my Pi via Putty, with the IP address *192.168.137.113*, I get "Network error: Connection timed out" error.

This is my first boot by the way.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you complete the setup of your Pi before trying to SSH into it?

Comment: @tlhIngan What kind of setup are you talking about? I thought I would be able to do the setup once I ssh into it. Can I do the setup with my laptop? Sorry, first time Pi user here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like a PC, you need to install the OS first. I personally prefer downloading an OS image and writing it to a card, but some people prefer the NOOB installer (that's it's actual name).
For NOOBS, follow [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/).
To download a Raspbian (or other OS) image and write it to a card yourself, follow [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md) instead.

Comment: Well, I have an SD card pre-imaged with NOOBS, but I guess I need to connect it to a monitor and a keyboard first, to do all the configurations. I will try it tomorrow and will let you know.

Comment: @massakrienen Yes. NOOB isn't an OS, it's a downloader and installer for a number of OS's. :)

Comment: Oh I see, I am downloading the Raspbian now then. This should work.

Comment: Yep, by connecting my Pi to a monitor, I was able to access it. Turns out the _Advanced IP Scanner_ got the wrong IP address. Thanks anyways.